# Circle covering whole screen after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://object.design

The above given website has an interesting animation when clicked on its menu button. I tried a lot but failed to make such animation. The small circle expands when clicked and covers the whole screen. Please help !!!

Comment: That website's design is so bad...

Comment: Maybe, but do you know how to do the animation i asked for ??

Comment: I can see how they've done it from looking at their code using Chrome's Developer Tools. You should be able to do the same, though it might take a bit more time. The problem with your question (and the reason it's getting downvoted) is that it shows zero effort. You should show your code so far.

Comment: The website does not work in Edge browser cause of `clip-path` - if that matters... for a design studio website... hmhm

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks, i'll keep this in mind

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice in the chrome inspector, that effect is done with css with the clip-path property. Play with those values and you will see how the size of the circle changes and the position.

```
clip-path: circle(150% at calc(100% - 25px - var(--page-component-margin,20px)) calc(25px + var(--page-component-margin,20px)));
```

I hope it helps you!